# What are the three assets of Muhammad ibn Abdul Wahhab?

Tags: tawheed, assets

I heard a lot about ***the three assets*** of **Muhammad ibn Abdul Wahhab**.

I would like to know what are they? And is it mandatory to learn them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muhammad bin Abdul Wahhab Is the remand of the Da'wa of Tawhid have written many books in this topic like **The Three Assets** or **The Three Fundamental Principes** of Islam. In this book he about **different topics**:

### 1. ***Four Points (Issues)*** that every Muslim should learn

He (may Allah have mercy on him)says:

> You should know, may Allah have mercy on you, that we should learn 
>   four points:
>
> - Knowledge: which consists in knowing Allah, knowing His Messenger, and  knowing the religion of Islam by knowing the proofs from the
>     Qur’an  and the Sunnah.
> - Acting according to this knowledge.
> - Calling other people to this knowledge.
> - Persistence in the face of adversity that results from calling the people to it.

The first point resume the three Fundamental Principes of Islam that Bin Abdul Wahhab made as title of this book.

---

### 2. ***Three Things*** and act according to them

> He, azza wa jall, began with knowledge first before saying and acting.
>   Know, may Allah have mercy on you, that every Muslim, male and female,
>   should learn these three things and act according to them:
>
> - That Allah has created us, has given us sustenance, and has not left us without guidance. He has sent His messenger to us; whosoever
>     obeys Him is destined to Paradise, and whosoever disobeys is consigned
>     to Hell. The evidence is in His saying:(73:[15](http://quran.com/73/15)-[16](http://quran.com/73/16)).
> - Allah does not accept that any partner is associated with him in worship, be he an exalted angel or a messenger prophet. The evidence
>     is in His saying:[(72:18)](http://quran.com/72/18).
> - Whosoever bears obedience to the Prophet and worshipped Allah alone should not take for friend those who deny Allah and His messenger,
>     even if they were his nearest kin. The evidence is in His
>     saying:[(58:22)](http://quran.com/58/22).

---

### 3. ***The Three Fundamentals*** that every Muslim should know

> If you were asked “What are the three fundamentals that must be
>   understood by every Muslim?”, say: “A worshipper should know his Rabb
>   (Cherisher and Sustainer), his religion, and his Prophet, sallallahu
>   ‘alayhi wa sallam.
>
> - **The First Fundamental: Knowing Allah**
> - **The Second Fundamental: Knowing the Religion of Islam through evidences.**
> - **The Third Fundamental: Knowing your Prophet Muhammad, sallallahu ‘alayhi wa sallam.**

Comment: Copy-paste answer are not accepted here on [islam.se]. meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/953

Comment: This is not a copy paste. This is a **citation**.

Answer (score 4):

Three assets is a book he wrote.  It's also called "The Three Fundamentals" =

1. Knowledge of Allah

   - Existence, oneness and worshiping Allah alone
2. Knowledge of Islam with evidences

   - Iman, Islam and Ihsan
3. Knowledge of Rasulullah (Prophet)

   - The seal of the Prophets, did not speak from his desires and everything he said was truth.

Obviously the importance of these three are fundamentals of our religion and clearly mentioned in the Quran.  Knowing them is what differs between believers and disbelievers.